# How to get video Title, Artist and Duration using VIDEO FILE PATH?

Tags: android, mediastore

how to get the media info like the Title and Artist of the Video using only its FilePath from sdcard??

ACTIVITY A

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // MOVE TO CLICK POSITION
        if (videoCursor.moveToPosition(position)); {
            videoPathColumnIndex = videoCursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);

            String path = videoCursor.getString(videoPathColumnIndex);
            videoIntent = new Intent(this, Play.class);
            videoIntent.putExtra("keykey", path);
                    videoIntent.putExtra("bmpbmp", bmp);
                    startActivity(videoIntent);

        }
}
```

ACTIVITY B

```
private void getMediaInfo() {
        videoIntent = getIntent();
        extras = videoIntent.getExtras();

        String path = extras.getString("keykey");
            Bitmap = (Bitmap) videoIntent.getParcelableExtra("bmp");
        MediaStore.Video.Media.
}
```

how to use the path of the video to list the videos Title, Artist, or Duration using the path?
how to properly pass img that will not affect performance issue?

Comment: put some of your try out codes and ask the question

Comment: when i pass the bitmap and fetch it from activity B and asign it to ImageView the image is not shown? my question is what can i do with the path only, can i get the Title, artist and duration of the video with using only the path of the video? how to do get media information from the video using only the path of the video?